# Message box to TabBarController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, message

I created a message box into the `FirstViewController` of my `TabBarController`:

```
- (void)pressedButton:(id)sender {
     [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Snap it" message:@"Take a picture"
                               delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]
     show];
```

When the user clicks on "Ok", I want them to be redirected to the `SecondViewController`.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your tab bar controller connected to a "`IBOutlet`" (or have some other reference to it), switching tabs is as easy as updating the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedIndex) property (I've linked the Apple documentation for you).

***EDIT:***

Change your code to this.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // if you have connected your tab bar controller to an IBOutlet named myTabBarController
    if(myTabBarController)
    {
        // first tab bar controller is zero, second tab bar controller is 1, etc.
        myTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;         
    } else {
        NSLog( @"tabBarController is nil and probably not set correctly" ); 
    }
}

- (void)pressedButton:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView * alertView = 
        [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Snap it" message:@"Take a picture" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    if(alertView)
    {
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

This assumes you've set your tab bar controller to an IBOutlet correctly.  Notice also that I've set the "delegate" on the alert view to "self" (i.e. the "`clickedButtonAtIndex`" method has to live in the same object & class if using "`self`" as a delegate).

Comment: Thanks for the feedbacks.I very new into coding, how would I know if it's connected to an "IBOutlet"?

Comment: If your tab bar controller exists in your storyboard (or xib file), you can set it to an "`IBOutlet`" and access it that way.  If you are creating your tab bar entirely in code, you can keep a reference to it as an instance variable.

Comment: I found the IBOutlet: 

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView* stepsTableView;

Now how to link it with the message box?

Cheers,

F

Comment: that is one IBOutlet, but that's not the IBOutlet for your tab bar controller.

Comment: Hmmm, I see!

Can I connect the message box to a ViewController out of the tab bar controller?

Comment: I've edited my answer for you.  Hopefully this is enough to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

Let me have a go at it :)

Cheers,

F